# IMPORTHTML ARRAY_LITERAL

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, unique, google-query-language

I'm trying to import multiple urls from finviz. The list of URLS are dependent of the results due to pagination of the table, but I'M unable to find a work around to make use of so many IMPORTHTML's without avoiding the ARRAY_LITERAL error, any help would be appreciated.

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=21&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=41&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=61&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=81&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=101&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=121&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=141&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=161&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=181&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=201&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=221&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=241&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=261&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=281&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=301&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=321&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=341&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=361&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=381&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=401&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=421&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=441&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=461&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=481&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=501&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=521&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=541&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=561&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=581&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=601&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=621&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=641&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=661&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=681&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=701&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=721&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=741&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=761&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=781&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=801&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=821&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=841&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=861&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=881&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=901&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=921&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=941&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=961&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=981&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""})},
"select Col1,Col2,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11")
```

Comment: formula works for me. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Well your right, just to end up with realisation that it's been a internet issue and not the query itself -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=21&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=41&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=61&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=81&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=101&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=121&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=141&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=161&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=181&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=201&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=221&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=241&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=261&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=281&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=301&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=321&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=341&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=361&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=381&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=401&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=421&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=441&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=461&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=481&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=501&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=521&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=541&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=561&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=581&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=601&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=621&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=641&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=661&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=681&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=701&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=721&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=741&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=761&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=781&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=801&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=821&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=841&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=861&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=881&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=901&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=921&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=941&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=961&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,earningsdate_thismonth,fa_epsqoq_o15,fa_grossmargin_o20,sh_avgvol_o750,sh_curvol_o1000,ta_perf_52w10o,ta_rsi_nob50&ft=4&o=perfytd&r=981&ar=180","Table","19"), {"","","","","",""})},
"select Col1,Col2,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11 where Col1 matches '^\d+'", 1))
```

[image]